# Get content of a header tag searching by header tag name

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-scripting

I'm scraping a page and I have to get the number of employees from this format:

```
<h5>Number of Employees</h5>
<p>
            20
</p>
```

I need to get the number "20" the problem is that this numbers isn't always in the same header, sometimes is in "h4" and there are more ''h5" headers, so I need to find the data that is contained in the header named: "Number of Employees" and the extract the number that is in the contained paragraph

This is the link of the page

http://www.bbb.org/chicago/business-reviews/paving-contractors/lester-s-material-service-inc-in-grayslake-il-72000434/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the easiest way is to find an element that contains the "Number of Employees"-text, and then simply take the paragraph after that, assuming that the paragraph always follows right after.

Here's a quick and dirty piece of code that does this, and prints the number out:

```py
parent = soup.find("div", id='business-additional-info-text')
for child in parent.children:
    if("Number of Employees" in child):
        print(child.findNext('p').contents[0].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'normalize-space(//*[self::h4 or self::h5][contains(., "Number of Employees")]/following-sibling::p[1]/text())'
```

Comment: is that the Xpath? I try it and get a quite long response, not just the number

Comment: sorry I was just giving you an idea, please check the corrected xpath